# What is a normal form in mathematical logic?What are its practical applications?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

What is a normal form in mathematical logic .What are its practical applications.Does this normal form have any relation with the one we see in database design such as 1NF,2NF,3NF ... etc

Comment: Are you talking about disjunctive normal form and conjunctive normal form?

Comment: There are like 20 different kinds of normal form that occur in varying contexts. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_form) for a sample. None have any direct relationship with database normal forms I'm aware of. There is a general connotation that a normal form is a particularly nice/convenient form something can take. e.g. any sentence in first order logic is equivalent to one in prenex normal form, which means all its quantifiers are out front and none are embedded in subformulas.

Comment: [Conjunctive Normal Form](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/courses/02240/Tautology.pdf) gives a decision procedure for tautology (alternative to truth table method).

Comment: @Matthew Daly yes I was talking about conjunctive normal form

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen your answer makes sense.Thanks for the reference

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA .Thanks for the answer